# Poisson model with overdisperssion

Tags: predictive-modeling, bayesian, poisson

I'm working with a dataset $X$ (of length $N$) of count data, which looks like:

[image]

I developed a statistical model which can be improved, so I'm asking for any suggestions, for instance, differnet likelihoods or prior selection, different approach, anything...

**My model**

I'm trying to get the parameters of the likelihood of the data, so thaht I can get a posterior predictive density function, credible intervals and so on. Let's say, I want to model the generative process of the data given some parameters, $f(X|\theta)$

This data shows a large overdispersion ($\bar X << var(X)$), thus a Poisson likelihood, $f(X|\lambda) \sim \mathcal{Poisson}(\lambda)$, is not a good choice.

Reading literature about count data with overdisperssion, I decided to model $f(X|\lambda)$ as a *Negative Binomial* distribution, thus $f(X|\lambda) \sim \mathcal NB(r, p)$

**Parameter estimation**

In order to not to end up with a very complex set-up, **I've performed bayesian estiamtion of the hyperameter $p$**, letting $r$ be computed from the data: in a *Neagative Binomial* distribution, $r$ is related to the first and second moments of the distribution following:

$
r = \frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2 - \mu}, \text then
$

$
\hat r = \frac{\bar X^2}{var(X) - \bar X}
$

The whole set-up is:

- **Likelihood**: $f(X|p) = \mathcal NB(\hat r, p)$
- **Prior**: $f(p) = \mathcal Beta (0, 0)$ (non informative, improper prior)
- **Posterior**: $f(p|X) = \mathcal Beta (0 + \hat rN, 0 + \sum X)$

which returned the following posterior predictive distribution:

[image]

The first and second moments of the predictive posterior distribution are very close to those in the data (I've let the data have a huge impact in the posteriors since I've choosen a non-informative prior). Also, the point estimate posterior predictive (using $\mu_p$) does not differ from an averaged predictive posterior distribution over all possible values of $p$.

Once again, any suggestions for improvement?

**EDIT**

What about a zero-truncated negative binomial distribution?

Comment: How many data points do you have? How many features?

Comment: 10^4 data points, no features at the moment... are you thinking in performin regression with some features? I could add as features the number of pages per document, for instance

Comment: I was mistaken, thinking you are doing regression here... Maybe you can add a little context

Comment: I trying to estimate the parameter $p$ of the likelihood function, so that I can end up with credible intervals, momemts, and so on... I'll clarify it in the post

Answer (score 0):

One option is to estimate a non-parametric function. Instead of assuming a functional form of the data, use something like [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) (KDE) to estimate the probability density function.

Another option is [bootstrap sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) to get credible intervals and other statistics.